# SQL Query & Grouping Row Data From Different Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query that works fine however I am trying to get a few of the rows consolidated if for example the first column (Name) is an exact match. I've tried delcaring a variable, using for XML, etc. but can't seem to get it working.

```
SELECT        MasterName.Last+ ', ' + MasterName.First+ ', ' 
              +MasterName.Middle AS NameCombined, MasterName.Type, 
              JailIntake.Booking_Status, JailIntake.Intake_Date, 
              JailIntake.Agency, MasterDescriptors.DOB, JailCharge.Suffix_1, 
              JailCharge.Charge_Literal, JailIntake.Incident_Nr, 
              JailCharge.Bond_Amount, Pictures.UnitID, ct500.code, 
              Pictures.IType

FROM          RMS.dbo.MasterName AS MasterName INNER JOIN
              RMS.dbo.MasterDescriptors AS MasterDescriptors ON 
              MasterName.Suffix_1 = MasterDescriptors.Suffix_1 AND 
              MasterName.Incident_Nr = MasterDescriptors.Incident_Nr AND 
              MasterName.Agency = MasterDescriptors.Agency AND 
              MasterName.Module_ID = MasterDescriptors.Module_ID INNER JOIN
              RMS.dbo.JailIntake AS JailIntake ON 
              MasterDescriptors.Module_ID = JailIntake.Module_ID AND 
              MasterDescriptors.Incident_Nr = JailIntake.Incident_Nr AND 
              MasterDescriptors.Agency = JailIntake.Agency AND 
              MasterDescriptors.Suffix_1 = JailIntake.Suffix_1 INNER JOIN
              RMS.dbo.JailCharge AS JailCharge ON JailIntake.Incident_Nr = 
              JailCharge.Incident_Nr AND JailIntake.Agency = 
              JailCharge.Agency AND JailIntake.Module_ID = 
              JailCharge.Module_ID INNER JOIN
              IMAGES.dbo.Pictures ON JailIntake.Incident_Nr = 
              JailCharge.Incident_Nr AND 'ABBV^' + JailIntake.Incident_Nr + 
              '^^^^INT^IN^MNI^' = Pictures.UnitID INNER JOIN
              PIMSTABL.dbo.ct500 AS ct500 ON ct500.code = 
              JailIntake.Inmate_Type
WHERE         (MasterName.Type = 'IN') AND (JailIntake.Booking_Status = 'IJ' 
              OR JailIntake.Booking_Status = 'OF') AND 
              (JailIntake.Agency = 'ABBV') AND (Pictures.IType = '1106')

ORDER BY      MasterName.Last
```

I won't include all the columns it generates by the SELECT portion but the ones I'm concerned with show up like this:

```
NAME OF PERSON       CHARGENUMBER     CHARGEDESCRIPTION

Doe, Jane                001               TEXT
Doe, Jane                002               TEXT
Doe, Jane                003               TEXT
Johnson, John            001               TEXT
Johnson, John            002               TEXT
Thompson, Tommy          001               TEXT
Williams, Wendy          001               TEXT
Williams, Wendy          002               TEXT
```

My ultimate goal is to have it look like:

```
NAME OF PERSON       CHARGENUMBER          CHARGEDESCRIPTION

Doe, Jane            001, 002, 003         TEXT, TEXT, TEXT
Johnson, John          001, 002                TEXT, TEXT
Thompson, Tommy          001                      TEXT
Williams, Wendy        001, 002                TEXT, TEXT
```

Comment: `SQL` is not right tool for above formatting

Comment: you could try at application layer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp([NAME OF PERSON] VARCHAR(100),CHARGENUMBER VARCHAR(100), CHARGEDESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Doe, Jane','001','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Doe, Jane','002','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Doe, Jane','003','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Johnson, John','001','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Johnson, John','002','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Thompson, Tommy','001','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Williams, Wendy','001','TEXT')
INSERT INTO #Temp VALUES('Williams, Wendy','002','TEXT')
```

Then change the values into comma separated.

```
SELECT
    [NAME OF PERSON],
    STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + t.CHARGENUMBER
        FROM #Temp t
        WHERE t.[NAME OF PERSON] = T1.[NAME OF PERSON]
        ORDER BY t.CHARGENUMBER
        FOR XMl PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS CHARGENUMBER
    ,STUFF((
        SELECT ', ' + t.CHARGEDESCRIPTION
        FROM #Temp t
        WHERE t.[NAME OF PERSON] = T1.[NAME OF PERSON]
        ORDER BY t.CHARGEDESCRIPTION
        FOR XMl PATH('')
    ),1,1,'') AS CHARGEDESCRIPTION
FROM #Temp T1
GROUP BY [NAME OF PERSON];
```

Hope this helps you.